# Events not propagating across react components

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have the following react components:

```
class Button extends React.Component {
  constructor(props){
    super(props);
    this.state = { disabled: false };
  }

  render() {
    return <button disabled={this.state.disabled} onClick={this.clicked.bind(this)}>Save</button>;
  }

  clicked(event) {
    this.setState({disabled: true});
  }
}

class Form extends React.Component {
  contructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = { foo: "bar" };
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <form onSubmit={this.submit.bind(this)}>
        <input valueDefault={this.state.foo} />
        <Button />
      </form>
    );
  }

  submit(event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    // do some stuff
  }
}
```

However, when the button is clicked the clicked method is triggered but the submit method isn't.  Is there some way I can make the event propagate?  Is there some reason the event isn't propagating like a normal html form event?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since setState will re-render the entire component the event will stop there and cannot continue till the ancestor form. Instead you can handle button disable in form's onSubmit. Something like this

```
 class Button extends React.Component {
    constructor(props){
      super(props);
      this.state = { disabled: false };
    }

    render() {
      return <button disabled={this.state.disabled}>Save</button>;
    }

    clicked(event) {
      this.setState({disabled: true});
    }
  }

  class Form extends React.Component {
    constructor(props) {
      super(props);
      this.state = { foo: "bar" };
    }

    render() {
      return (
        <form onSubmit={this.submit.bind(this)}>
          <input valueDefault={this.state.foo} />
          <Button ref="button" onSubmit={this.submit.bind(this)}/> <----- Added reference here
        </form>
      );
    }

    submit(event) {
      event.preventDefault();
      var button = this.refs.button; // <---- Added ref to button
      button.setState({disabled:  true}); <---- set disabled state to button
    }
  }
```

Here is a demo  **http://jsbin.com/ginune/edit?html,output**